# simple solution for 3d collision detection and response

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution

I'm having great difficulty trying to implement collision detection and response in a 3d game

What are some simple solutions someone can use to implement smooth collision and response similar to games like Quake? I can see there are a lot of different ways to do collision and response but that makes it even more confusing, Im not sure which method is the best solution to sit down with.

So I was wondering what is the goto solution for the average programmer? All I have found online are very complicated incomplete mathematical explanations which I have a hard time understanding. Is this really a topic that requires an entire textbook to understand??

Perhaps theres a library ? Ive tried looking into bulllet but it seems to require heavy knowledge of physics. The best solution I have found is in a software called darkbasic, where it somehow handled sliding collision automatically and all the user had to do was desginate which object were to be handled. Was wondering maybe theres something similar to that

Comment: "*Is this really a topic that requires an entire textbook to understand?*" Yes, actually. :) I've heard [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Game-Physics-Engine-Development-Commercial-Grade/dp/0123819768) is pretty good. It sounds like you might like [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) or [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/), which have built-in physics simulations that are simpler to use.

Comment: I have to fully agree with @Anko. It certainly is a topi that requires an entire textbook. Actually more than one. So after you do some basic reading, I can't help but recomend the famous: http://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Collision-Detection-Christer-Ericson-ebook/dp/B00CLZIKC2/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1447668487&sr=1-1&keywords=real+time+collision+detection. Also, please let us which platform you are current using. I myself started with DarkBasic, but I also think today you would profit more from the builtin Physics engine present in Unity or Unreal Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Simple Collision Detection Libraries are commonly built-in to 3d engines or as feature but here's a few that I know that are widely used that don't have the complexities and added Physics system:

**Coldet**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/coldet/

**OZCollide**
http://www.tsarevitch.org/ozcollide/

There's also [Blitz3D](http://www.blitzbasic.com/), which is similar to DarkBasic (Language wise). It is Free and Open Source now and has a built-in collision system.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a project that has near-round characters and cube enviroment (walls, trees, etc...) there we managed collisions by embebing every char object in a sphere and getting the magnitude of the 0,0,0 point of the object (exactly the center of it), then you can easily check if magnitude + radius of item A is inn or out of magnitude + radius of item B and fire a collision if it's in it.

I didn't wrote it so i can't give you exact maths but i could help you to find out some new and efficient ways to detect collisions.

Hope it helps

Comment: I realize that you probably aren't allowed to post comments yet, but if you can help the OP, so write it in your answer. Otherwise it's not an answer.